# Why my nginx config doesn't work?

Tags: nginx, phalcon

I'm trying to setup nginx to begin working with phalcon, here's the config :

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost.dev;
    set $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/html/phalcon/public';
    root        $root_path;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    charset     utf-8;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files     $uri =404;

        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path/public;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I tried all possibilites but still I can't get it working.
Any clues?

Comment: after reading the docs here :
http://php-phalcon-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/nginx.html,
adjusted some values and voila, it works now!

Comment: If the solution isn't already in the answers, please don't hesitate and post it. This will benefit all.

Answer (score 0):

look here

```
location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
    root $root_path;
}
```

Comment: Some text to the snippet (explaining why to change the `root` value) would be nice

Comment: because your static resource in ./public path